# "cd" terminal order doesn't work

Tags: 12.10, command-line, bash

I'm trying to install ClamAV 0.98 of which first step is

```
`cd' to the directory containing the package's source code and type `./configure' to   
configure the package for your system.
```

The problem is I do it and I get

```
bash: cd: /MYUSERNAME/Programas_descargados: No existe el archivo o el directorio 
[file or directory doesn't exist]
```

Can someone tell me why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your answer you wrote "Programas descargados" instead of "Programas_descargados", maybe you think replacing the space with a underscore is the way, but its not, the correct way is:

```
cd Programas\ descargados
```

Comment: @ntrpris Also, you should consider that quotes are very good in this sense: `cd "Programas descargados"`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
cd /home/MYUSERNAME/Programas_descargados
```

or

```
cd ~/Programas_descargados
```

The problem is you forgot to specify that you're in a subdirectory of your home directory.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Of course I tried before asking and I got the same error @JKB

Answer (score 0):

They only way I could solve it was renaming "Programas descargados" for "Programas-descargados". Everything in a single word.